# Finding out utf-8 value of small Tethe char

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

There is something confusing about this,

I'm trying to get the utf-8 int value of the small Tetha character, which should be 225182191:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta#Character_Encodings
But:

```
    public static void main(String... args){

    char c='Ɵ';
    System.out.println((byte)c);
}
```

Prints: -97 (????)
I did change my text encoding scheme on eclipse from MacRoman to UTF-8

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov it returns (-1), From the method's comment i see (at)return .... -1 if the character has no numeric value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoding of the text source file has nothing to do with how things are at runtime.

A Java *char* is a 16-bit wide value. It is always implicitly UTF-16.

When the compiler generates a *.class* file char literals are transcoded to UTF-16 and stored in an *int* structure within the class' [constant pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4). Strings are converted to a modified UTF-8 for compactness reasons.

When either is loaded by the JVM they are represented as UTF-16 values/sequences in memory.

Transcoding the value from UTF-16 to UTF-8:

```
char c = '\u03B8'; // greek small letter theta θ
for (byte b : String.valueOf(c).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
  int unsigned = b & 0xFF;
  System.out.append(" ").print(unsigned);
}
```

*FYI: The three-byte decimal sequence `225 182 191` is "modifier letter small theta" and not "greek small letter theta"*

Answer (score 0):

It should be casted to an int, or alternatively, used as String and call the method `codepointAt(0)`

```
        char c='Ɵ';
    System.out.println((int)c);
    System.out.println("Ɵ".codePointAt(0));
```